# Ajax Contact Form with Dropdown Select Where Email is Sent

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, contact-form

I followed this tutorial to create a contact form: http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form

The form works great, but I want to add in an option for the user to select an item in a dropdown which will determine which email address the form will send to. I've researched this all day but can't figure out exactly how to implement it with this particular code.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
<div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
<div id="contact_results"></div>
<div id="contact_body">
    <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Phone</span>
        <input type="text" name="phone1" maxlength="4" placeholder="+91"  required="true" class="tel-number-field"/>&mdash;<input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />
    </label>
        <label for="subject"><span>Regarding</span>
        <select name="subject" class="select-field">
        <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
        <option value="Advertise">Advertisement</option>
        <option value="Partnership">Partnership Oppertunity</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label for="field5"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required="true"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
    $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }   
        });

    if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'country_code'  : $('input[name=phone1]').val(), 
            'phone_number'  : $('input[name=phone2]').val(), 
            'subject'       : $('select[name=subject]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to_email       = "myemail@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
} 

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
    die($output);
}

//email body
$message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
}
}
?>
```

This seems like something many people have asked about but I can't find a solution that includes everything- HTML and all. I'm new to PHP, but I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution for this by adding an 'if' in the PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
<div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
<div id="contact_results"></div>
<div id="contact_body">
    <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Phone</span>
        <input type="text" name="phone1" maxlength="4" placeholder="+91"  required="true" class="tel-number-field"/>&mdash;<input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />
    </label>            
<label for="subject"><span>Send To</span>
        <select name="sendto" class="select-field">
        <option value="email1@email.com">email1</option>
        <option value="email2@email.com">email2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
        <label for="subject"><span>Regarding</span>
        <select name="subject" class="select-field">
        <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
        <option value="Advertise">Advertisement</option>
        <option value="Partnership">Partnership Oppertunity</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label for="field5"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required="true"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Script would be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

    var proceed = true;
    //simple validation at client's end
    //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
    $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
        }
        //check invalid email
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
            $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
            proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
        }   
        });

    if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
    {
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
            'country_code'  : $('input[name=phone1]').val(), 
            'phone_number'  : $('input[name=phone2]').val(), 
            'sendto'       : $('select[name=sendto]').val(),
            'subject'       : $('select[name=subject]').val(), 
            'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
            if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                //reset values in all input fields
                $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
            }
            $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');
    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
});
</script>
```

and then your PHP would be

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to_email = filter_var($_POST["sendto"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
} 

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
    die($output);
}

//email body
$message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
    die($output);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about adding the email options into the HTML. Fantastic and easy solution!